# Saving JSON into Realm

Tags: swift, realm

For my project I want to save data I'm getting from an API in realm and then display it in a table view.
The JSON will look like this:

> `{"books":[{"author":"Chinua Achebe", "title":"Things Fall Apart","imageLink":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=plk_nwEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api"}]}`

I've tried a few different things, but I can't figure out how to decode and store the JSON properly. I have used this function before for parsing the JSON, but when I add the realm Code I'm getting errors.

My function for fetching the JSON is:

```
func fetchArticle(){

let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https:/mocki.io/v1/89aa9fe9-fdba-463f-99b3-5d8b6bc1d32e")!)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {  (data,response,error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    self.books = [Books]()
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
    
    if let booksFromJson = json["books"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
        for bookFromJson in booksFromJson {
            let book = Books()
            if let title = bookFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = bookFromJson["author"] as? String, let imageLink = bookFromJson["imageLink"] as? String {
                
                book.author = author
                book.title = title
                book.imageLink = imageLink
            }
            self.books?.append(book)
            let realm = try! Realm()
            for books in bookFromJson {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(books, update: .all)
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
    
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
}
    task.resume()
}
    }
}
```

This is my Struct:

```
class Books: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var author: String?
    @objc dynamic var imageLink: String?
    @objc dynamic var title: String?
    
convenience init(author: String, imageLink: String, title: String) {
     self.init()
     self.author = author
     self.imageLink = imageLink
     self.title = title
  }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "author"
        }
        
        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case author
            case imageLink
            case title
}
  }
```

This are the errors im getting in the func:

[Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VWyv.png)

['let' declarations cannot be computed properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH7Pg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a 100 different ways to map your json to a realm object but let's keep it simple. First I assume your incoming json may be several books so it would look like this

```
let jsonStringWithKey = """
    {
        "books":
            [{
                "author":"Chinua Achebe",
                "title":"Things Fall Apart",
                "imageLink":"someLink"
            },
            {
                "author":"another author",
                "title":"book title",
                "imageLink":"another link"
            }]
    }
"""
```

So encode it as data

```
guard let jsonDataWithKey = jsonStringWithKey.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
```

Then, using JSONSerialization, map it to an array. Keeping in mind the top level object is "books" and AnyObject will be all of the child data

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonDataWithKey) as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let bookArray = json["books"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            for eachBook in bookArray {
                let book = Book(withBookDict: eachBook)
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(book)
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
}
```

and the Realm object is

```
class Book: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var author = ""
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageLink = ""

    convenience init(withBookDict: [String: Any]) {
        self.init()

        self.author = withBookDict["author"] as? String ?? "No Author"
        self.title = withBookDict["title"] as? String ?? "No Title"
        self.imageLink = withBookDict["imageLink"] as? String ?? "No link"
    }
}
```

Again, there are a LOT of different ways of handling this so this is kind of the basics that can be expanded on.

As a suggestion, Realm Results are live-updating objects that also have corresponding events. So a neat thing you can do is to make a results object your tableView datasource and add an observer to it.

Results objects work very much like an array.

As books are added, updated or deleted from realm, the results object will reflect those changes and an event will be fired for each one - that makes keeping your tableView updated very simple.

So in your viewController

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var bookResults: Results<PersonClass>? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var bookTableView: NSTableView!
    var bookToken: NotificationToken?

    self.bookResults = realm.objects(Book.self)
```

and then

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.bookToken = self.bookResults!.observe { changes in
      //update the tableView when bookResults change
```

Comment: I really wonder why not to use `JSONDecoder`

Comment: @Sulthan Good question. As I mentioned, *this is kind of the basics*. Keep in mind there's a top level key "books" to work with and JSONDecoder had some issues with  accepting top-level objects which are not arrays or dictionaries. I think that was resolved but don't have a link at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in terms of where you've placed your `catch` statement -- it should be in line with the `do { }` block. This might be easier to see if you format/indent your code (`Ctrl-i` in Xcode).

```
func fetchArticle(){
    
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https:/mocki.io/v1/89aa9fe9-fdba-463f-99b3-5d8b6bc1d32e")!)
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {  (data,response,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        self.books = [Books]()
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
            
            if let booksFromJson = json["books"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
                for bookFromJson in booksFromJson {
                    let book = Books()
                    if let title = bookFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = bookFromJson["author"] as? String, let imageLink = bookFromJson["imageLink"] as? String {
                        
                        book.author = author
                        book.title = title
                        book.imageLink = imageLink
                    }
                    self.books?.append(book)
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    for books in bookFromJson {
                        try! realm.write {
                            realm.add(books, update: .all)
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch { //<-- no need for `let error`
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume() //<-- Moved outside the declaration
}
```

Comment: Does this answer address to how to decode json to Realm objects and save them? or how to do handle the catch closure better? (I agree with you btw, just looking to see if this answers the question as well)

Comment: @Jay mine specifically deals with the errors that the OP listed at the end of their initial question. Looks like yours deals with the Realm issues more specifically but doesn't address the errors. Hopefully the combination of the two will help the OP. If you want to edit your answer to include the explanation of the syntax errors, I'm happy to delete mine.

Comment: Your answer is valuable for sure! So no changes necessary. They really need to handle the mentioned errors correctly. I just wanted to be sure there wasn't a code change in your answer that also addressed saving the Json data. Upvoted your answer.